# Why is a local min also a global min for convex functions?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

As the title states,

for an unconstrained minimizaton problem, of a convex function, why is it that the local minimum is also the global solution?

Comment: Are you assuming unconstrained optimization? If the problem is constrained then convexity of the constraint set is also necessary.

Comment: If $x$ is a local minimum, $f(x)\le f(y)$ for all $y$ in a neighbourhood of $x$. To prove that $x$ is a global minimum, you need to show that $f(x)\le f(z)$ for all possible $z$. Find a $y$ that is on the line segment between $x$ and $z$ and lies in the aforementioned local neighbourhood, then apply convexity.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I am assuming unconstrained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming unconstrained optimization, let $x^*$ be a local minima of $f$. Then $f(x^*)\le f(x)\ \forall x$ in some neighborhood of $x^*$. Now, let $y$ be a point on a line joining $x^*$ and $z$ such that $y$ belongs to this neighborhood. Then, $y=\alpha x^*+(1-\alpha)z$ for some $\alpha\in [0,1]$. Then, $f(x^*)\le f(y)=f(\alpha x^*+(1-\alpha)z)\le \alpha f(x^*)+(1-\alpha)f(z)\implies f(x^*)\le f(z)$ for $\alpha\ne 1$, if $\alpha=1$, then $y=z$ and $z$ is in the neighborhood mentioned before so by hypothesis, $f(x^*)\le f(z)$. Thus $x^*$ is a global minimizer.